# What is the best CLI tool to take memory dumps for C++ in Linux

Tags: memory, dump

What is the best CLI tool to take memory dumps for C++ processes in Linux. I have a program which monitors the memory usage of different processes running on Linux. For Java based proceses, I am using jstack and Jmap to take the thread and heap dumps. But, are there any good CLI tools take similar dumps for C++ based processes?? And if yes, how do we use them and once dump is taken how to analyse the dumps?

Any inuputs will be appreciated.

Comment: I can suggest gcore which is an open-source for dumping remote process. usage example can be found here : http://gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=gcore. another alternative is to open the process while running and then do "generate-core-file"

Comment: Thanks Zohar. gcore generates the core dump, but does it tell me what is loaded in the memory? Also, in case of high CPU usage, does taking the dump uing gcore help in debugging?

Comment: gcore basically suspend the process and than takes the dump. gcore is a process by itself, and runs pretty fast according to my experience. if the CPU load caused by the target process to dump, than it should be fast (since the process is suspended while dump is taken)

Comment: regarding the memory the answer is yes, you may try it and that load the dump file with gcc, and try to read its virtual memory

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using gcore which is an open source executable to dump for remote process. In order to achieve consistency, target process is being suspended while collecting memory, and resumed afterwards.

usage info can be found in the following link :

```
gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=gcore
```

another option is via gcc, by attaching the process to gcc instantiation and typing the 'gcore' command, and then detaching it.

```
$ gdb --pid=123
(gdb) gcore
Saved corefile core.123
(gdb) detach
```